# Why use ASCII code for letters of the alphabet in if statements, instead of using normal char data type?

Tags: c++, ascii

I'm reading some lines of code written by a colleague and he has written code the following:

```
int keych = 0;
keych = _getch();
if (keych == 104 || keych == 104 - 32) //Help
{
    printf(cHelp);
}
```

What I do'nt understand is that why does he not use simple char data type, this helps to write less code. What are the advantages of using that method instead of char data type to get user input?

Comment: What does this question have to do with Unicode?

Comment: There are no advantages. The compiled code is exactly the same. Your colleague is not very experienced. Using normal characters makes it immediately obvious what it is happening, unless you happen to memorize the ascii code for every character. Writing `' '` is much more meaningful than this mysterious number "32".

Comment: @nicol bolas because the if statement takes unicode characters, e.g. the 104 is the letter 'h' for help I think

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I thought the same :D

Comment: @Samir: I don't see anything there about "unicode characters". [`_getch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa297934(v=vs.60).aspx) doesn't return Unicode characters.

Comment: Your colleague should have his/her wrists slapped for magic-number programming.

Comment: Hint: don't use "magic" numbers. What is 104 ? What is 104-32 ?

Comment: Well, I can see him crying for help.  Think it through a bit, what is the Unicode code point for F1?

Comment: @NicolBolas probably because the unicode characters have been numbered. "keych == 104". How can the user enter 104 from the keyboard? this is unicode number that represents the letter 'h'. (within the if statement). I just wanted to know if coding it like this is better than using normal char data types but I think Sam Varshavchik answered it.

Comment: @Samir It's not Unicode, but an ASCII charcater code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz so in case if the user enters the letter 'h' or uppercase letter of it 'H'. This would be easier to read if used as char data types instead of getting the origin name of the keys which are in unicode. This probably is helpful if users have different types of keyboards e.g. american to spanish etc.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ah I see the confusion now hahaha. okay thanks for correcting me, not sure how to pronounce your name. Yes it is ASCII code. My bad fellows.

Comment: Making code readable far outweighs the amount of code generated.  There are a few exceptions, such as embedded systems that have very limited code and memory space.  Otherwise, readable code also helps reduce the quantity of injected defects.

Comment: @Samir - it **is** Unicode, as much as it's ASCII. Both encodings use the same character mapping for values that are less than 128. More important is that hard-coding numeric values that are intended to represent characters is a big mistake, because it builds in assumptions about the character encoding.

Comment: @Samir, I know that, but it's not obvious. R Sahu's answer below applies here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using

```
if (keych == 104 || keych == 104 - 32) //Help
```

to decide whether the input character is `'h'` or `'H'` is bad.

1. It is difficult to read.
2. It will work only on systems that use 104 and 72 for encoding `h` and `H` (such as ASCII).

It will be better to use:

```
if (keych == 'h' || keych == 'H')
```

or

```
if ( tolower(keych) == 'h' )
```

Comment: "Only ASCII" is perhaps an over-simplification - there are many encodings that have `h` and `H` at the same position as in ASCII, such as the ISO 8859 series of codings.  The important thing is that there are encodings, notably EBCDIC, that have different assignments for these characters.

Comment: @TobySpeight -- and, despite the comments in response to the question, Unicode code points whose values are less than 128 represent the same characters as ASCII.

Answer (score 2):

Oups, unicode and ascii are not exactly the same thing, or more exactly ascii is a subset of unicode (127 first code points). 104 or (0x98 in hexa) is the ASCII code for 'h', so no unicode is involved here. The only *advantage* of using ascii code is that it will break on a non ASCII system and there could still be EDCDIC system around... and additionaly as you were said in comment, 104 is more cryptic than 'h'.

TL/DR: never replace characters with their ascii code point unless you have serious reason to do so.

Answer (score 1):

It's good practice if not very intuitive for newbies to store character variables and pass them about as int. The standard library does that, fputc() takes and int not a char. In C, sizeof('a') yields 2 or 4 depending on the size of an int, not 1 for sizeof(char).

The reason is that int can hold EOF, which is not a  char and means end of input or error condition. There's also the effect that the code scales to unicode quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

The only time it's reasonable to refer to (printable) characters by their code points in an encoding is when you know that the data you are handling are not in native form for your program - this is only likely if you're implementing code conversion, either as a program like `iconv` or as a conversion layer in your program's i/o classes.  Normally you don't need to write such things yourself; that's what libraries are for.

Even if you are writing conversions, it helps to give names to the values you're using, e.g.

```
static const int UNICODE_LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_H = 0x68;
```

In the particular case in the question, assuming that `_getch()` is something like the Curses `getch()`, then you should expect it to be represented consistently with the character constants in your program source character set.